# mean.io assetmanager.init(... returns JS error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I want to use MEAN.io stack. I did the required initialization. Created the folder, did the npm install, got the libraries.

now in server/config/express.js I have

```
assetmanager = require('assetmanager'),
```

and

```
// Import your asset file
var assets = require('./assets.json');
assetmanager.init({ // this is line 75
    js: assets.js,
    css: assets.css,
    debug: (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),
    webroot: 'public/public'
});
```

and this gives me this error:

```
server/config/express.js:75
assetmanager.init({
             ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'init'
    at module.exports (server/config/express.js:75:18)
    at module.exports (server/config/system/bootstrap.js:49:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (server.js:20:54)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have the package installed.

```
npm info assetmanager version
0.1.3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author [mistakenly published an incompatible version of assetmanager](https://github.com/ReedD/node-assetmanager/commit/8f67f8fb91c392faa7b07daf5cb46d33af61ac7e#commitcomment-6500053). You can either use version v0.1.2 instead by running `npm install assetmanager@0.1.2` command.

Or change your code to be compatible with the latest. [Check the README for the example](https://github.com/ReedD/node-assetmanager).

Comment: Thanks, I changed init to process and updated to version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

Farid is correct that assestmanager pushed out an incompatable version.

The mean.io project has since been updated to use the 0.1.2 version. [Commit](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/commit/75189c4df8ccdaee1358264f7eb89cfb37692ef5)

All new mean.io projects will have the correct version.

For projects that do not work you can either change your package.json or manually run `npm install assetmanager@0.1.2`

**Please note that it is recommended to rather update your package.json to prevent issues when you change environments or go to production.**