# "Object #<Object> has no method 'init'" how to find where?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I've got a running application in Node.js with unit testing using Mocha.

Since a few day when I run my test using Mocha, the tests stops with this errors :

```
Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'init' Use --force to continue.
```

I try to find where in my last change or with finding all init method of my code but without success.

I try running node with --debug and put a breakpoint (with debugger;) but the code is not started.

I need to have a stack trace or a debugging method to find what goes wrong and where.

Any idea ?

Thx in advance

Comment: Could you give us more code and more information about the line that cause this issue ?

Comment: I just can't find the line causing the issue. That's the purpose of my question. How to find where is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what happens. THe case is described here : [mean.io assetmanager.init(... returns JS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949772/mean-io-assetmanager-init-returns-js-error)

For people who like me can be stuck with such message without any clue to resolve it, the solution was to run mocha with the command line.
mocha -d ./tests/**.js
When running in the command line and not with grunt-mocha, the full stacktrace is displayed showing where is the problem.

I hope this help !